# Escaping column with dot in UPDATE in PostgreSQL 9.3.9

Tags: postgresql

I need to fix few lines in Jira configuration in PostgreSQL. Unfortunatelly it uses dot notation in columns and I cannot fine a way how to escape it.

```
select * from "cwd_directory_attribute";
directory_id |  attribute_name     | attribute_value
        1 | user_encryption_method | atlassian-security
    10000 | ldap.user.filter       | (objectclass=person)
```

No escaping:

```
psql:fix_directory.sql:1: ERROR:  column "ldap" of relation "cwd_directory_attribute" does not exist
LINE 1: update cwd_directory_attribute set ldap.basedn='ou=sandbox,d...
```

Single quote:

```
psql:fix_directory.sql:1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'ldap.basedn'"
LINE 1: update cwd_directory_attribute set 'ldap.basedn'='ou=sandbox...
```

Double quote:
psql:fix_directory.sql:1: ERROR:  column "ldap.basedn" of relation "cwd_directory_attribute" does not exist
LINE 1: update cwd_directory_attribute set "ldap.basedn"  ='ou=sandb...

Square bracket:

```
psql:fix_directory.sql:1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: update cwd_directory_attribute set [ldap.basedn]  ='ou=sandb...
```

E.g.

```
update cwd_directory_attribute set "ldap.basedn"  ='ou=sandbox,dc=eu' where directory_id=10100;
```

I found answers that double quotes shall work but they do not. I could modify the columns manually in some SQL editor, but I want to set up a script:

```
psql -f fix_directory.sql jiradb7
```

What is the proper escaping for columns in UPDATE procedure?

Update:

```
select "ldap.secure" from "cwd_directory_attribute";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select "ldap.secure" from "cwd_directory_attribute";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing column *values* and column *names*.

Your table has a column named `attribute_name` which contains the value `'ldap.user.filter'` (and supposedly `'ldap.basedn'` in a different row).

So what you want is:

```
update cwd_directory_attribute 
   set attribute_value = 'ou=sandbox,dc=eu' 
where directory_id = 10100
  and attribute_name = 'ldap.basedn';
```

Comment: Good catch! I was blind.